# android ListView: how to notify datasource when delete one row?

Tags: android, listview

I add one delete-image at each row, so when click image and delete this row, the following code is MyDapater:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        ItemViewHolder holder = new ItemViewHolder();
        ...
        holder.deleteImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_icon);

        holder.deleteImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (Integer)v.getTag();
                _list.remove(pos); // _list is a List storage the data
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.deleteImage.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));

    return view;
}
```

and in Activity ,my data is storage a List and the following code:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(this, _list);//
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

so ,when click delete-image, this row will go.My question is: how do activity know which row delete?

Comment: Is you adapter a subclass of ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter?

Comment: It's not of `Activity`'s knowledge. It's all in you.when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, `ListView` will refresh it's `View`s by calling `getCount()` and `getView()`...

Comment: You are removing one record from the data that u have given to the adapter to populate a list, so once u have deleted an item in the data if u r using notify data set changed to the adapter it doesnt know whether item deleted or added it will populate the item in the list view based on the data that u have given..if u are familiar with the getView() u can easily conclude this function.

Comment: subclass of BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

In short it doesn't.

If you want the activity to know what row is deleted you will need to tell it. My preferred method is an interface.

```
public interface DeleteListener{
    public void rowDeleted(int pos);
}
```

and the activity should implement it

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements DeleteListener{
```

when creating the adapter pass the activity reference

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(this, _list, this);
```

and in the adapter fire an event on delete

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, List _list, DeleteListener dListener){
    //save the listener to a field
}
...
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer)v.getTag();
            _list.remove(pos); // _list is a List storage the data
            dListener.rowDeleted(pos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: I have the same point. But I don't know the ListView I use right or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass database object in adapter constructor and in the click event you delete your item from database.